# How to replace text without caring for spaces between words in php

Tags: php

I want to know, how can I replace the text with something else without the spaces affecting the process.
(`"Hi, I'm here!" Will be replaced with "bye"`)

Like this(`Value ==> ReplacedValue`):

```
Hi,I'mhere!                  ==>   bye
Hi, I'm here!                ==>   bye
Hi,  I'm here!               ==>   bye
Hi  ,     I'm        here!   ==>   bye
```

Now using `str_ireplace` (`str_ireplace("TheOriginalWord", "TheReplacement", $data)`) won't do what I want, it'll do this:

```
Hi, I'm here!                ==>   bye
Hi,  I'm here!               ==>   Hi,  I'm here!
Hi  ,     I'm        here!   ==>   Hi  ,     I'm        here!
```

Comment: Use `preg_replace()`, then you can use a pattern that matches a variable number of spaces.

Comment: Would `Hi,I'mhere!` also be replaced?

Comment: @kerbholz yeah, it will

Comment: Could remove all spaces first or use Barmar's `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
preg_replace('/Hi\s*,\s*I\'m\s*here!/i', "bye", $data);
```

`\s*` matches zero or more spaces. If you only want to match one or more spaces, use `\s+` instead.

Comment: it returns an error

Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '!' found in file.php on line 132

Comment: Needed to escape the `'` inside the string.

Comment: But you should have gotten a syntax error because of the quoting problem, not that error.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer is good, but just in case you need something reusable, you could use the following function:

```
function replace_spaceless(string $subject, string $from, string $to): string
{
  $pattern = '/' . preg_replace('/(?<!^)\s*\b\s*(?!$)/', '\\s*', preg_quote($from, '/')) . '/';
  return preg_replace($pattern, $to, $subject);
}
```

This is basically `str_replace` except it ignores spaces. To do so, it builds a regular expression replacing all word boundaries (except at beginning/end of the string) by `\s*`, and pass it to `preg_replace`.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/o5om1**